Parallel transport of a vector on a $2d$ plane
Consider a 2d plane such that there is a curve $\gamma$ that traces a circle of radius $r=r_0$. Suppose a vector $A^\mu = (A_1, A_2)$ is attached on the circle as shown in the image below. I want to find the parallel transport equation of this vector around the circle in polar coordinates and also find the solution for $A_1, A_2$.

The parallel transport equation is given by,
\begin{equation}
\dot{A}^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda} A^\nu \dot{x}^\lambda = 0
\end{equation}
where $x^\mu$ is the coordinate of the curve. One way to coordinatize the circle is to let $x^\mu = (r_0 \cos \theta, r_0 \sin \theta)$.

I can think of two ways to solve this but I'm not sure how to make the two consistent and whether either or both of them are wrong.
Method 1.
The metric is given by,
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2
\end{equation}
The metric does not depend on $\theta$ so there is a constant $C = r^2 \dot{\theta}$. The Christoffel symbols are,
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^1_{22} = -r, \qquad \Gamma^2_{12} = \Gamma^2_{21} = \frac{1}{r}
\end{equation}
The parallel transport equations are,
\begin{align}
& \dot{A}_1 -r_0^2 A_2 \dot{\theta} \cos \theta = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad \dot{A}_1 -C A_2 \cos \theta = 0\\
& \dot{A}_2 + A_1 \dot{\theta} \cos \theta - A_2 \dot{\theta} \sin \theta = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad \dot{A}_2 + \frac{C}{r_0^2} A_1 \cos \theta - \frac{C}{r_0^2} A_2 \sin \theta = 0
\end{align}
This is a coupled ODE which I'm not sure how to solve. On the other hand, I think this method might be wrong since $r_0$ is a constant and so the Christoffel symbols should vanish.
Method 2.
The induced metric on the circle is,
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = r_0^2 d\theta^2
\end{equation}
The Christoffel symbols vanish so that the parallel transport equations are,
\begin{align}
& \dot{A}_1 = 0\\
& \dot{A}_2 = 0
\end{align}
So, $A_1 = a$ and $A_2 = b$ where $a,b$ are constants. This means that the vector $A^\mu = (a,b)$ has constant length and direction as it is parallel transported along the circle.
Any help in figuring out the correct method?

Please define "parallel" before anything.  It is unclear how the vector is supposed to  be transported.

Both are correct; the difference is whether you're considering the circle as being in embedded in the ambient space ($\mathbb{R}^2$) or not. If yes then there is a normal component as you have discovered.

@VincentThacker The circle is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so does that mean that Method 1 is the correct way? On the other hand, they should both give the same answer right?

@mathemania In method 1, you are considering parallel transport in the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ along the path given by the circle, so the connection is trivial and the vector remains unchanged in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which you can show by solving the differential equations). This is not the same as parallel transport in the circle itself considered as a 1D manifold (regardless of whether it is embedded). So you need to clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

@VincentThacker I'm considering parallel transport in the manifold along the path given by the circle. In rectangular coordinates it is indeed trivial, in polar coordinates I believe it is not as trivial but not difficult.

@mathemania Parallel transport is a tensorial construction and does not depend on the coordinate system used. Like I said earlier, the difference between your approaches boils down to whether you're considering the manifold to be $\mathbb{R}^2$ or the circle.

Parallel vector field along a curve means that the "covariant differential of a vector along the curve vanishes" which implies
\begin{align}
\dot{A}^\mu+\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\lambda}A^\nu\dot{x}^\lambda=0
\end{align}
I think you need to think about your vector components
Method 1 - (metric on a 2 dimensional manifold): vector in polar coords: $\mathbf{A}=A_r\mathbf{e}_r+A_\phi\mathbf{e}_\phi$
Method 2 - (metric on a 1 dimensional manifold): vector in polar coords: $\mathbf{A}=A_{\phi'}\mathbf{e}_{\phi'}$
